# How to align paragraph tag to start at the same level for each new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code below demonstrate paragraph tag that has contents which seems not to start at same level for each new line. However, some lines starts with extra spaces than other. therefor, I used `display: inline;` to align the text all to the left which has yet not align the element content to start at the same level.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row centered">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h4 >We proud for the services we provide to the client</h4>
                <p class="fonts">We believe ideas come from everyone, everywhere. At Al-AndalusSD is computer software company. Our dedicated web app developers have completed many web-applications for varity of customers in the industry of e-learning, managment, e-comearce, mangament and much more. </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->



.fonts{ 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline;

    float: left;}
```

[image]

Comment: So whats the issue?

Comment: still I cant starts the line all on the same level. each line seems to have extra space at the start.

Comment: Maybe post a picture or a link to an online version to let us see what the issue is?

Comment: can you make a plunker or soemthing with this I dont see it happening.

Comment: okay i will upload it

Comment: Remove the `centered` class

Comment: Or add `text-left` to `<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">`

Comment: Yeah text-left has worked.